# How can I repair my DataView Web Part in 2010

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part, upgrade

A client's DVWP links aren't working after a move to 2010.  A 3 layer grouping exists on the custom page.  Year, Month, Dept. Documents exist just fine under this grouping.  Once the Dept layer is expanded the list shows.  The document icons make each file appear to be checked out (they are not) and the icon is not linked like it is in 2007.  I am able to write some custom XSL and link the icon but not to my liking.

The issue is the web part looks at files from a different folder and I am having trouble linking to them cleanly.  If I use @FileRef the path doubles (sites/folder/sub/sites/folder/sub) and if I use @FileLeafRef, the path stays in the current folder. I can hard code the server name and then @FileRef to make it work, but don't like that option.  Here's a small code sample.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
<a TABINDEX="-1" onclick="return...... target="_blank" href="http://MySrv/{@FileRef}"><IMG BORDER="0" alt="{@FileLeafRef}" title="{@FileLeafRef}" src="/_layouts/images/{ddwrt:MapToIcon(string(@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type),string(@File_x0020_Type))}" /></a>
```

Comment: a server-relative url href="/{@FileRef}" does not work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was the first thing I attempted.  It makes sense that should work but it did not. I also tried ./

Comment: Derek.  I don't know why it didn't work day one, but it worked today.  Please post as answer.

Comment: "It makes sense that should work but it did not". That should be SharePoint's motto :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a server-relative url href="/{@FileRef}" .